# How can use Python to mark words in a sentence string depending on whether they come after one specific word and before a full stop?

Tags: python, nlp

I have a list of strings containing job descriptions like the following:

`direct or coordinate an organization's financial or budget activities to fund operations, maximize investments, or increase efficiency. may serve as liaisons between organizations, shareholders, and outside organizations. may attend and participate in meetings of municipal councils or council committees. represent organizations or promote their objectives at official functions, or delegate representatives to do so.`

I already have some python code that splits up each word in the description, and gives it a number of attributes, for example how many times it appears in the description, its position (in terms of numerical rank) or its POS tag (whether it's a noun, verb etc.). So for example, if the job description was just "plan schedules", my program can already give me the following:

`[('plan', 'plan', 'NN', 0, 2, 5, 'construction managers', '11-9021.00', 245), ('schedule', 'schedul', 'NN', 1, 1, 1, 'construction managers', '11-9021.00', 245)]`

I wanted to add to this a flag/boolean which would highlight, for each word in the definition, whether it comes *after* the word 'may' and *before* a full stop. Essentially, I would be looking for a list of booleans for each description, which I could zip to the above structure as the 10th attribute and know for each word whether it comes between 'may' and a full stop.

Any suggestions on how I could achieve this?

Comment: Have you considered using regex?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to find the keyword appearing *anywhere* between the word "may" and a full stop, i.e. whether someone is allowed to perform a certain task.

After having compiled your list of keywords, you can use [regular expressions](https://regexr.com/) and the `re` library to search for matching strings.

The `re.search` method returns a Match object if the regular expression is found in the string, otherwise `None`. But these two cases can also be converted to a boolean variable:

```
import re
def may_matcher(string, keyword):
    return bool(re.search(r'may\s(\w*\s)*'+keyword+'\s*(\w*\s)*\w*\.',string))
```

Applying this little function gives you the desired boolean:

```
string = "may attend to guests."
may_matcher(string, "attend")
may_matcher(string, "help")
```

The first line evaluates to `True` whereas the second one evaluates to `False`.

You can then use list comprehension to go through all of your keywords:

```
keywords = ["attend", "help"]
may_list = [may_matcher(string,keyword) for keyword in keywords]
```

It should be noted that one should be careful with **negative sentences**: A sentence with **"may not"** would also be matched by this function! If such sentences also exist, you would have to modify the regex.

Comment: Thank you so much @nikoniko. This works well for my purposes except in one way. When a word appears multiple times in a job description, sometimes between a 'may' and a full stop and other times not, the boolean assigned seems to be the latter in all occurrences of the word. 

For example, I have a description that reads:

direct or coordinate an organization's financial or budget activities. may direct or coordinate activities of businesses.

The boolean I am getting for the first instance of 'direct' is "True", despite the fact that it does not meet the criteria. Any suggestions? Thx!

Comment: I just noticed a mistake in the regex - you have to include a space character `\s` after "may" and optionally `\s*` after the keyword. Now the regex should match your string.

Comment: Hi again - apologies for the long delay in replying. I had to suddenly drop this due to other work duties and have only just managed to come back to it! Thank you for your comment, I have amended the code to add ```\s``` accordingly. However, I am still getting a similar issue. For the following sentence, "molds odd shaped brick pipe and other refractory products using hand molding tools. may be designated according to product molded as brick molder.", both the first instance of "brick" and the second are being flagged as after a may... Any thoughts? Thanks again!